# Testing Angular JS with WebStorm: unresolved function or method inject()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webstorm, angular-mock

I'm developing web an app using AngularJS + TypeScript, and Karma + Jasmine for testing purposes.

The problem is that WebStorm continues pestering me with the following error, despite the fact that all of my tests compile well:

> Unresolved function or method inject()

[image]

I've added angular-mocks typings:

[image]

and provided angular-mocks JavaScript library for IDE:

[image]

But the problem still exists. I know that as a workaround, one can declare corresponding variable, but honestly I don't really think that this is a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me using typings (`npm i @types/angular-mocks`):

[image]

Please try invalidating caches

Comment: I've reinstall angular-mocks type, using `npm i @types/angular-mocks` command as was proposed and invalidated caches, but with no success.

Comment: sorry, didn't read your post carefully enough^( This works for javascript, but not for typescript. Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26723 for updates